# From core controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

This is my Welcome controller

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    }

    function index()
    {
        if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
            redirect('/auth/login/');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('welcome', $player);
        }
    }
}
```

MY_Controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tank_auth');

        if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {

            $player = $this->tank_auth->get_userdata($this->tank_auth->get_user_id());

            if ($player === NULL) {
                $this->tank_auth->logout();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: player

Filename: controllers/welcome.php

Line Number: 17
Hi,
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: username

Filename: views/welcome.php

Line Number: 1
```

Do I really need to reassign all data ?? Are there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$player` is set in `__construct()` of your `MY_Controller` class. How is `index()` function in `Welcome` class supposed to get it's value automatically?

Instead define `$player` as a protected property in your `MY_Controller` class so that every controller class extending it can use the value of `$player`.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $player;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tank_auth');

        if ($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
            $this->player = $this->tank_auth->get_userdata($this->tank_auth->get_user_id());

            if ($this->player === NULL) {
                $this->tank_auth->logout();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now your Welcome class can use its value.

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    }

    function index()
    {
        if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
            redirect('/auth/login/');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('welcome', $this->player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The authenticate object should know the player, not the controller.

Comment: In the code, value of $player is set in __construct() of MY_Controller and used in index() of Welcome controller. So you need to set the value of $player in a public/protected property of MY_Controller so that Welcome can access it. Another solution is to do `$player = $this->tank_auth->get_userdata($this->tank_auth->get_user_id());` in Welcome.